# antd style does not work with antd-mobile style

Tags: antd, antd-mobile, ant-design-pro

.webpackrc.js, is it wrong?

When I `import {Select} from antd` the Select has no style, just antd-mobile style work.

```
entry: "src/index.js", 
theme: 'src/theme.js',
extraBabelPlugins: [[
  "import",
  {libraryName: "antd-mobile", 
  "libraryDirectory": "lib", "style":true}, 
  {libraryName: "antd",
  "libraryDirectory": "lib", "style": true} 
]],
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you wrote the right component `Select`，beginning with a capital letter.
or try another component to see if the same?

Answer (score 0):

Try importing the css manually by adding

`import 'antd/dist/antd.css';` or `import 'antd/dist/antd.less'`

Source: https://ant.design/docs/react/introduce